# Witcher 3 meditation has stopped regenerating my potions/bombs

Tags: the-witcher-3

I used all of my bombs to kill a wyvern in a quest in velen , since then meditating has stopped regenerating my bombs and potions (still heals me though).

I reloaded to an earlier save when I know it was working and still nothing...

Checked my difficulty, it has been on easy mode all game and hasn't changed..

What happened?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will only regenerate potions / bombs if you have a high-quality alcohol in your inventory.

These are listed on the **Alchemy and Crafting** tab of the inventory, and include items like "Alcohest", "Dwarven Spirit", and "Temerian Rye".

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! Couldn't find mention of it anywhere. That explains where my dwarves spirits have been vanishing off to as well.